# Why Valgrind detects memory leak in Dbus application?

Tags: memory-leaks, embedded-linux, valgrind, dbus

I am using Dbus for interprocess communication.
I am using dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block to send the data over dbus and for Reading I am using  dbus_connection_read_write(connection, 0). Both are running in separate thread.

We are getting memory leak in valgrind as mentioned below:

```
==16199== 792 (368 direct, 424 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 75 of 78
==16199==    at 0x484AC14: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:760)
==16199==    by 0x4E05FBB: dbus_malloc0 (in /lib/libdbus-1.so.3)
==16199==    by 0x4DEC867: dbus_message_new_empty_header (in /lib/libdbus-1.so.3)
==16199==    by 0x4DF1613: _dbus_message_loader_queue_messages (in /lib/libdbus-1.so.3)
==16199==    by 0x4DFDE5B: _dbus_transport_get_dispatch_status (in /lib/libdbus-1.so.3)
==16199==    by 0x4DFDF37: _dbus_transport_queue_messages (in /lib/libdbus-1.so.3)
==16199==    by 0x4DFF6CF: do_reading (in /lib/libdbus-1.so.3)
==16199==    by 0x4DFFCEF: socket_do_iteration (in /lib/libdbus-1.so.3)
==16199==    by 0x4DFDBCB: _dbus_transport_do_iteration (in /lib/libdbus-1.so.3)
==16199==    by 0x4DDBA77: _dbus_connection_do_iteration_unlocked (in /lib/libdbus-1.so.3)
==16199==    by 0x4DDD10F: _dbus_connection_block_pending_call (in /lib/libdbus-1.so.3)
==16199==    by 0x4DF520F: dbus_pending_call_block (in /lib/libdbus-1.so.3).
```

This memory leak is incremental over a period of time.
Can please someone help me to fix this leak.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please show a code example so we can help you find the problem.

Comment: You are probably missing calls to dbus functions that free resources. I know nothing about dbus so I can't help any more than that.